# mvc4 model is null when RedirectToAction calls view

Tags: c#, view, model, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I will start by saying I am new to MVC4... so be gentle

I have a model

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
}
```

which is just an extention of the standard log in model, I have just added the CurrentBalance variable.

I have then added code to the AccountModel which uses the username and password to log into another system, on a successful log in I update the CurrentBalacnce value with the returned value, and then use RedirectToAction to load the logged in page.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Log into the server

        if (server_loggedIn)
        {
            server.LogOut();
        }
        if (server.LogIn("****", "****", "****") == 0)
        {
            if (server.GetUserInfoByUserName(model.UserName) == 0)
            {
                if (server.GetUserTransactionInfo(model.UserName) == 0)
                {

                    model.UserName = server.m_sLoggedInUser;
                    model.CurrentBalance = server.m_currentBalance;
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Account", new {model});
                }
            }
          }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

as you can see I am using the standard code for now while I get my head round it all, but when I then load the index page I get a null value in the model

```
@model Print_Management.Models.LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Your Account";
}

@section Header {
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Home", null, new { data_icon = "arrow-l", data_rel = "back" })
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
}

<p>
    Logged in as <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>.
    /n\nCurrent Balance <strong>@Model.CurrentBalance</strong>
</p>

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Deposit", "ChangePassword")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff")</li>
</ul>
```

I am sure I am doing something very basic wrong... but any help would be much appreciated, as going forward I will need to pass variables to and from the views..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass complex objects when redirecting. You will have to explicitly decide which properties of this model you want to be send along with the redirect as query string parameters:

```
return RedirectToAction(
    "Index",
    "Account", 
    new {
        username = model.UserName,
        password = model.Password, // oops, be careful the password will appear in the query string
        rememberMe = model.RememberMe,
        currentBalance = model.CurrentBalance
    }
);
```

Actually the correct way to do this is to not send any parameter when redirecting:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
```

and then inside the target action you will be able to retrieve the currently authenticated user from the forms authentication cookie:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;

    // Now that you know who the current user is you could easily 
    // query your data provider to retrieve additional information about him
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin, I will try both methods, but, how do I use the variable in the view ? I have changed my controller to use the individual elements now, and not a complex variable, sorry, but like I said, I am new to MVC, and using the model.CurrentValue doesn't work still as the model variable is still null

Comment: anyone ?? would like to get this sorted before I am back at work on Monday if possible... Thanks

Comment: oh, just realised, when I use the user variable from the view page, I don't get access to the currentbalance variable I added ?

Comment: But why did you add this variable on the `LoginModel`? This doesn't make sense. The `LoginModel` should be used only when authenticating. It would make more sense to add this variable on your user profile. And then when you query for it in the Index action, once authenticated, you will be able to retrieve the value from the database.

Comment: that would make more sense, but I put it in there because I was using the loginmodel for logging into my other server, as I said at the start, I am a novice with MVC, but I am picking it up, so how would I add it to the user profie, as I agree that would be better..